# member "Renderer::backgroundTex" is not a type name

Tags: c++, directx

I am trying to create a renderer for directX, but there is an error which I cannot seem to debug. I am getting:

> syntax error: '->'

about the -> in the draw call. I am also getting the error:

> member "Renderer::backgroundTex" is not a type name

with the "backgroundTex.Get()" part of the draw call. I have no idea what the problem is, so any help would be nice. Thank you.

```
DX::ThrowIfFailed(CreateWICTextureFromFile(device.Get(), L"Art/Background.png",
    nullptr, backgroundTex.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()));
ComPtr<ID3D11Resource> resource;

DX::ThrowIfFailed(
    CreateWICTextureFromFile(device.Get(), L"Art/Background.png",
        resource.GetAddressOf(),
        backgroundTex.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()));

ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> background_;
DX::ThrowIfFailed(resource.As(&background_));

CD3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC backgroundDesc;
background_->GetDesc(&backgroundDesc);


SpriteBatch->Draw(backgroundTex.Get(), screenPos, nullptr,
    Colors::White, 0.f, origin, g_XMOne,
    SpriteEffects_None, 0.f);
```

Comment: What is `SpriteBatch`?

Comment: SpriteBatch is what Directx TK uses to Draw. It is initialized with: spriteBatch = std::make_unique<SpriteBatch>(context.Get());

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/SpriteBatch

Comment: You're using `SpriteBatch` (with a capital `S`) before the arrow, which is the name of a type.  You should be using `spriteBatch` (with a lowercase `s`) to name the variable.  This is one reason why using identifiers that only differ in case is not a good idea.

Comment: Thank you I think I might change the name of spriteBatch